# Combining of two IQueryables don't work

Tags: sql, asp.net

I'm working on a ASP.NET-application in which is a page with two selection fields.
One for searching all persons to the selected department and another one for searching persons with the given name (or a part of it with LIKE).
For each selection field i get a query which gets an IQueryable-object of the same framework entity.
But when i try to combine the IQueryable-objects and their results with Intersect (because of AND-Logic), just the first query is handled and the second not.
What have i done wrong?
Maybe there is a mistake in my queries?

Here are the queries:

The first for searching the persons to the selected department.

```
{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[InstanceID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[InstanceID] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Extent1].[InstanceID] ELSE 0 END AS [C1], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[bHidden] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[bHidden] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Extent1].[bHidden] ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C2], 
    [Extent1].[txtLastName] AS [txtLastName], 
    [Extent1].[txtFirstName] AS [txtFirstName], 
    [Extent1].[txtEMail] AS [txtEMail], 
    [Extent1].[txtAlternativeEMail] AS [txtAlternativeEMail], 
    [Extent1].[txtGID] AS [txtGID], 
    [Extent1].[txtPhoneNumber] AS [txtPhoneNumber], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[iImportance] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[iImportance] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Extent1].[iImportance] ELSE 0 END AS [C3], 
    [Extent1].[Teamlead] AS [Teamlead]
    FROM (SELECT 
    [Person_Teamlead].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[InstanceID] AS [InstanceID], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[WiW_URL_PersonID] AS [WiW_URL_PersonID], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtAccount] AS [txtAccount], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtTitle] AS [txtTitle], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtLastName] AS [txtLastName], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtFirstName] AS [txtFirstName], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtPhoneNumber] AS [txtPhoneNumber], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtEMail] AS [txtEMail], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtGID] AS [txtGID], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtDomain] AS [txtDomain], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtFax] AS [txtFax], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtMobilePhone] AS [txtMobilePhone], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtRoom] AS [txtRoom], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtAddress] AS [txtAddress], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[dtLastUpdate] AS [dtLastUpdate], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[bHidden] AS [bHidden], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[iExtern] AS [iExtern], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtOrganisationUnit] AS [txtOrganisationUnit], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtStreet] AS [txtStreet], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtZip] AS [txtZip], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtLocalityName] AS [txtLocalityName], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtCountry] AS [txtCountry], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[iToDelete] AS [iToDelete], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[dtToDelete] AS [dtToDelete], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[iImportance] AS [iImportance], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[iManualInput] AS [iManualInput], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtAlternativeEMail] AS [txtAlternativeEMail], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[Teamlead] AS [Teamlead]
    FROM [dbo].[Person_Teamlead] AS [Person_Teamlead]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Person_Department] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[DepartmentID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[PersonID] = [Extent1].[PersonID])
    )) AND ([Extent1].[InstanceID] = @p__linq__1) AND (0 = [Extent1].[iToDelete]) AND ((0 = (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[bHidden] IS NOT NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)) OR (0 = [Extent1].[bHidden]))}
```

And the second query is for searching persons to the given name.

```
{SELECT 
    [Project1].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[txtLastName] AS [txtLastName], 
    [Project1].[txtFirstName] AS [txtFirstName], 
    [Project1].[txtEMail] AS [txtEMail], 
    [Project1].[txtAlternativeEMail] AS [txtAlternativeEMail], 
    [Project1].[txtGID] AS [txtGID], 
    [Project1].[txtPhoneNumber] AS [txtPhoneNumber], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[Teamlead] AS [Teamlead]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
        [Extent1].[txtLastName] AS [txtLastName], 
        [Extent1].[txtFirstName] AS [txtFirstName], 
        [Extent1].[txtPhoneNumber] AS [txtPhoneNumber], 
        [Extent1].[txtEMail] AS [txtEMail], 
        [Extent1].[txtGID] AS [txtGID], 
        [Extent1].[txtAlternativeEMail] AS [txtAlternativeEMail], 
        [Extent1].[Teamlead] AS [Teamlead], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[InstanceID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[InstanceID] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Extent1].[InstanceID] ELSE 0 END AS [C1], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[bHidden] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[bHidden] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Extent1].[bHidden] ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C2], 
        CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[iImportance] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[iImportance] IS NOT NULL)) THEN [Extent1].[iImportance] ELSE 0 END AS [C3]
        FROM (SELECT 
    [Person_Teamlead].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[InstanceID] AS [InstanceID], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[WiW_URL_PersonID] AS [WiW_URL_PersonID], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtAccount] AS [txtAccount], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtTitle] AS [txtTitle], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtLastName] AS [txtLastName], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtFirstName] AS [txtFirstName], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtPhoneNumber] AS [txtPhoneNumber], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtEMail] AS [txtEMail], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtGID] AS [txtGID], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtDomain] AS [txtDomain], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtFax] AS [txtFax], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtMobilePhone] AS [txtMobilePhone], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtRoom] AS [txtRoom], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtAddress] AS [txtAddress], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[dtLastUpdate] AS [dtLastUpdate], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[bHidden] AS [bHidden], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[iExtern] AS [iExtern], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtOrganisationUnit] AS [txtOrganisationUnit], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtStreet] AS [txtStreet], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtZip] AS [txtZip], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtLocalityName] AS [txtLocalityName], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtCountry] AS [txtCountry], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[iToDelete] AS [iToDelete], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[dtToDelete] AS [dtToDelete], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[iImportance] AS [iImportance], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[iManualInput] AS [iManualInput], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[txtAlternativeEMail] AS [txtAlternativeEMail], 
    [Person_Teamlead].[Teamlead] AS [Teamlead]
    FROM [dbo].[Person_Teamlead] AS [Person_Teamlead]) AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[InstanceID] = @p__linq__0) AND (0 = [Extent1].[iToDelete]) AND ((0 = (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[bHidden] IS NOT NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)) OR (0 = [Extent1].[bHidden])) AND ([Extent1].[txtLastName] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N'~')
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Teamlead] DESC, [Project1].[C3] DESC, [Project1].[txtLastName] ASC, [Project1].[txtFirstName] ASC}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it.
Small cause, big result!
I have forgotten to set the result of the Intersect to the original query.
I made

```
query1.Intersect(query2);
```

instead of

```
query1 = query1.Intersect(query2);
```

That's why just query1 was always executed.